# Getting [object Object] in javascript when I want the value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've looked at some similar questions, but not seeing exactly what I am doing wrong.  I am passing a dict from a .py file to a file that uses javascript.

I know that the javascript file is getting my dict like this:

```
var numbersFromServer = [{"a": "45", "b": "22", "c": "7"}];
```

So, when I try something like this:

```
var numbersFromServer = {{ numbers_list|safe }};

var NumbersViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    theNumbers = [];
    for (var key in numbersFromServer) {
        theNumbers.push(numbersFromServer[key]);
    }

    self.num_display = ko.observableArray(theNumbers);
}

ko.applyBindings(new NumbersViewModel());
```

I am getting [object Object] when I want to get the actual values (45, 22, 7).

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

A fiddle that shows what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Znk3q/1/

Comment: is this correct?   {{ numbers_list|safe }}

Comment: Yes, I know that part is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have object in array so to get element you shoud

```
for (var key in numbersFromServer[0]) {
    theNumbers.push(numbersFromServer[0][key]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, duh.  Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an array containing one object. To access it you need to

```
for (var key in numbersFromServer[0]) {
    theNumbers.push(numbersFromServer[0][key]);
}
```

Comment: Shaddow responded a couple minutes sooner, but thank you so much anyways!  (I'd upvote, but I can't yet...)